# Trigger Javascript Function when user clicks anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a ModalPopupExtender that needs to be hidden whenever the user clicks anywhere else on the page, window, or scrollbar. I have a function and it works if i set it to a div tag but what about when the user clicks the windows scrollbar?

```
function HideList() {
    $find("<%=ModalPopupExtender1.BehaviorID%>").hide();
}

<div id="maindiv" onclick="HideList()">
    Elements...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it's not possible to target the scroll bar using JavaScript.

However, you can target the scroll event and any click event on the window:

```
$(window).bind('scroll click', function() {
    alert('Boo');
});
```

Comment: Yup it worked! I replaced alert('Boo'); with HideList(); Thanks again!